# Set size of detail section in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I m generating Bill report using crystal report in VS2008..in that, details section size is dynamic.
i.e. depend on number of records, it changes. so if I've 10 records the report view is full page that is k ..but if i have 2 records in details sections, then whole page footer section getting stick to details page..so whole alignment is getting change

so is there any way to set details section fixed i.e. for 10 records and if records exceed more, then all records on same page and remaining data will go on next page i.e report footer,page footer.

Is there any setting in crystal report

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, i can give you some tips on how you can approach your desired outcome.

The Crystal Reports engine has the following characteristics.

1. The **Report Header** appears on the top side of the first page only.
2. The **Page Header** appears on the top side of every page (on the first page it is under the Report Header).
3. The **Report Footer** appears only once, on the bottom side of the detail section on the last page.
4. The **Page Footer** appears on the bottom side of every page.

There is a capability in every section that allows you to suppress it if you don't need it. It can be done by right clicking the bar of the section that you want to suppress and pressing the suppress choice from the menu that will appear.

Consider the 2 following cases.

[image]
[image]

If you want to achieve the first case, change the height of the Page Footer to a value that will allow only 10 records to show on the Details section, include all the footer information in the Page Footer and suppress the Report Footer. If you want the same result but with the footer information appearing only on the last page, right click the bar of the Page Footer and select Section Expert. From there, press the x+2 sign next to the Suppress CheckBox and add the following code there.

```
if pagenumber <> totalpagecount then
    true
else
    false
```

If you want to achieve the second case, change the height of the Page Footer to a value which will allow only 10 records to show on the Details section and include all the footer information in the **Report Footer** section.

*In both cases the Report Header is suppressed.*

Answer (score 4):

Go to Section Expert
select report footer
 Tick the Print at bottom page and Keep together option

Problem will be solved

Answer (score 0):

First of all fix height detail section by right click on detail section Detail Section->Section Expert click on paging Tab->Check in New Page Before checkbox and beside it (x+2)button write formula-> (Suppose you want 8 rows to display in your report per page and additional rows(9th row,10th row and so on... to another page) IF Remainder (RecordNumber, 9) = 0 THEN TRUE ELSE FALSE so now your height is fixed.. and for blank rows suppose 2 records/rows are coming from data table/data source then from 8 fixed rows , 6 rows should be blank rows for that.. design your detail section with fields and keep report footer(section 4) blank with with some spaces(i want 8 rows fixed so keep size of 8 rows blank assuming in report footer) and put footer details in your section 5(page footer)..

if your header or footer is not visible on another page then put all header parts details in page header and footer details in page footer

:)