# Crystal Report - two sub report with fix detail section

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

I'm generating letter using crystal report designer in VB 2008. The letter contain two sub reports with same source. Currently my letter design is look like this
[letter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3BPh9.png)

what i'm trying to achieve is i want to fixed the height of the detail section. for example if my letter just have two detail, height of page footer should not fit with the detail section, it should not be move and the empty part of the detail section remain blank. And if the detail section exceed the height that have been fixed it should create a new page for the rest detail. i've tried this solution [Set size of detail section in Crystal Report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262928/set-size-of-detail-section-in-crystal-report) but it did not work, the page footer still move according to detail section height. For information i created the sub report with following structure :

1. I suppressed the report header
2. I put all the header information on page header
3. I suppressed the report header
4. i put all the footer information on page footer with extra space on top of the footer content according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262928/set-size-of-detail-section-in-crystal-report%20but%20it%20did%20not%20work) solution

and in my main report i put the sub report both in report footer section within report footer a and report footer b for each sub reports. is that possible to do what i'm trying to achieve ? Thanks in Advance !

Comment: should be page footer not report footer.. if you are looking to display the subs multiple times

Comment: hi @maSTAShuFu thanks for your reply. I have tried the suggestion from you, but the result is still the same, the height between detail section and page footer section still not fixed. Any other suggestion ? Thanks

Comment: You dont need a detail section coz you are running a sub report

Comment: @maSTAShuFu in my main report i did not use detail section, i imported both sub reports on each page footer a and page footer b in my main report. what i mean with detail section is in my sub reports which is contain the letter, the main report is just to show my sub reports twice at one page, any suggestion ? TIA

Comment: @SeptianRizky explain this: you have put each of your subreports in a page footer section of your main report and your desire is that if the detail section of each of your subreport exceeds a specific number of records then your main report to go to new page?