# Crystal Report Show All Detail Section on One Page VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

Currently My Crystal Report use PRS Paper / Computer Form Paper with size 9.5" x 11" (where every 5.5", the paper have a tear line). So i am setup my Paper Size on crystal report to 9.5" x 5.5" and get the layout that i want.

So far this is my layout
[My Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFUwc.png)

Where my footer is set to print at bottom of page so if the detail section have only 1 row, the detail section keep showing blank space to make it fit the page size.

Is is possible for me to make detail section height dynamically? Because i have seen before a report that have minimum height (same as my layout) but when the detail section get more than 50 row the report height is change dynamically based on Computer Form Paper (9.5" x 11").

The report will fit the footer to the Tear line , so user can tear the report on the tear line. And on the report preview all data only showed in one page, where the page size is changed to 9.5" x ??" (depends on how many rows show on detail section)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the size of page footer so it only allows a certain amount of data on Details.

Check this  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17265362/10191493).

Comment: Already find that answer but it's different from what i want. That answer use 2 Page with every page have header and footer. What I want is if the report is more than X Record that makes the report 2 page, then I want to use script or formula to change paper height dynamically. So far i used 2 report. if record <=x then use report1.rtp else if record >=x than use report2.rpt (rpt1 use 9.5" x 5.5" and rpt2 use 9.5" x 11")